# Наиболее часто задаваемые типы вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы, общие-сообщения

**Цель проекта:** классифицировать наиболее частые вопросы на Stack Overflow на русском.

**Задачи:** выявить наиболее частые вопросы, проанализировать ответы и комментарии к ним, разработать рекомендации по решению заданных в них проблем.

**Причина возникновения:**
Я вижу, что многие вопросы на стеке соответствуют какому-либо шаблону, например, домашние задания или вопрос о нерабочей библиотеке. Я считаю, что в целом сообществу было бы легче задавать и отвечать на подобные посты, если будет существовать место, в котором есть такие шаблоны и вся нужная информация по их оформлению и решению.

**Что сюда нужно писать:**

1. **Тип вопроса**, например, "Почему не работает *$librain-name$?"*
2. **Рекомендации по его решению**, например, "Проверить наличие библиотеки в проекте, если нет, ..."
3. **Рекомендации по орфомлению вопроса:** (*необязательно*), например, "Обязательно напишите источник, откуда вы взяли данную библиотеку и ..."

Comment: Вы только что придумали велосипед на замену т. н. "каноническим вопросам" :)

Comment: Пару раз прочитал и все ещё с трудом понимаю, о каком проекте вы говорите. Похоже, что вы хотите как-то помочь сайту, систематизировать знания и помочь участникам. Это очень здорово, спасибо вам. Но пока что не ясно, какую проблему вы хотите решить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Как раз таки систематизировать знания по самым популярным темам. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Эта страница на Мете и есть мой проект.

Comment: Цель проекта классифицировать, ок. А для чего?  Что потом с этим делать?

Comment: Кидать в вопросы, соотвествующие этим шаблонам.

Comment: @TrashboxBobylev что кидать в вопросы?

Comment: Кажется, я начал понимать. Вы хотите сделать шаблоны для задавания типичных вопросов?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: в качестве практического применения шаблоны для разного типа вопросов могли бы быть полезны [ментору, когда он помогает новому пользователю вопрос задать](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up). Не реалистично ожидать, что сами спрашивающие будут читать (качество заметной доли вопросов можно улучшить, если сделать mcve обязательным чтением и/или инструмент, который помогает шаги из него выполнять), а [некоторым] менторам, чтобы велосипед не изобретать, может быть полезно шаблоны под рукой иметь.

Comment: related: [What can we put in a question template to help people ask better questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357951/4279)

Answer (score 2):

**Общие рекомендации по решению проблемы перед постингом:**

1. Загляните в поисковик, впишите в поисковую строку ваш вопрос и пощелкайте по первым ссылкам; возможно, кто-то за десять лет до вас решил данную задачу.
2. Отладьте ваш код до выступа пота. Если проблема в неверных данных, то вопрос может не иметь смысла висеть на данном ресурсе.
3. Перепишите проблемный код заново, проговаривая про себя замышленное поведение. Бывают случаи, когда такой кусок начинал работать верно.

**Общие рекомендации по написанию ответов:**

1. Будьте кратки. Нет, серьезно. Часто проблема кроется в неправильной формулировке решения самого автора вопроса и вам достаточно просто написать взгляд со стороны в трех-четырех предложениях.
2. Пишите простой и понятный код. Уровень автора вопроса чаще всего неизвестен, поэтому лучше готовиться к худшему исходу для вашего чувства собственного величия: "нубоватости" автора в данной сфере.
3. При любой возможности соблюдайте нейтральный стиль написания. Не давайте волю вашему плохому настроению, личной неприязни к автору, багам движка ресурса. Stack Overflow на русском - технический Q&A-сайт, излишней субъективности здесь не очень рады.